# Sql select statement selecting 4 value from same table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Hello everyone I have created two select statements but I want to merge them together to give one select statement that display only 4 record can someone help please?

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(month, BID.Date) AS Years, 
    COUNT(DATENAME(Month, BID.Date)) AS Total 
FROM 
    Auction 
INNER JOIN 
    BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID 
INNER JOIN 
    Item ON Auction.ItemID = Item.ItemID 
WHERE 
    (Auction.Status = 'Expired') 
    AND (Item.SellerID = @seller) 
    AND (BID.Status = 'Won') 
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(month, BID.Date)

SELECT 
    DATENAME(month, BID.Date) AS Years1, 
    COUNT(DATENAME(Month, BID.Date)) AS Total1 
FROM 
    Auction 
INNER JOIN 
    BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID 
INNER JOIN 
    Item ON Auction.ItemID = Item.ItemID 
WHERE 
    (Auction.Status = 'UnSold') 
    AND (Item.SellerID = @seller)  
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(month, BID.Date)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the results to look like? It could be interpreted in at least 2 ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(month, BID.Date) AS Years 
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Auction.Status = 'Expired' 
                   AND  Item.SellerID = @seller 
                   AND  BID.Status = 'Won'
               THEN  DATENAME(Month, BID.Date) ELSE NULL END) AS Total1
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Auction.Status = 'UnSold'
                   AND Item.SellerID = @seller
               THEN DATENAME(Month, BID.Date) ELSE NULL END)  AS  Total2

FROM       Auction   INNER JOIN  BID 
ON         Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID 
INNER JOIN Item 
ON         Auction.ItemID = Item.ItemID 
GROUP BY   DATENAME(month, BID.Date)
```

Comment: I NEED 4 ANSWER NOT TWO

Comment: @user3287068 Would you like to Elaborate what do you mean by Four results and not two can you show some sample data and desired output?

Comment: IT IS TELLING ME THE CRL TYPE IS NOT EXIST

Comment: Easy on the caps lock @user3287068